# Read env variable from file and output into another file

Tags: bash, docker

This question is somehow docker related, but I guess it is actually more for a bash expert.

I am trying to read the content of a `docker secret` file located at `/run/secrets/password` into an environment variable and then output it along with a few other stuff into another file.

This is the `docker compose entrypoint` directive I currently got to just write some contents into the `/opt/bitnami/redis/etc/sentinel.conf` file:

```yaml
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c 'bash -s <<EOF
      "/bin/bash" -c "cat <<EOF > /opt/bitnami/redis/etc/sentinel.conf
      port 16379
      dir /tmp
      sentinel monitor master-node redis-master 6379 2
      sentinel down-after-milliseconds master-node 5000
      sentinel parallel-syncs master-node 1
      sentinel failover-timeout master-node 5000
      sentinel auth-pass master-node MySeCrEtPaSsWoRd
      EOF"
      "/bin/bash" -c "redis-sentinel /opt/bitnami/redis/etc/sentinel.conf"    
      EOF'
```

Now I tried to replace the `MySeCrEtPaSsWoRd` with an environment variable that is set by the contents of a `docker secret` file instead, but I get the Following bash errors with my attemp:

```
bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: line 1: `"/bin/bash" -c "export PASSWORD="(<"/run/secrets/password")""'
```

Here is what I tried

```yaml
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c 'bash -s <<EOF
      "/bin/bash" -c "export PASSWORD="$(<"/run/secrets/password")""
      "/bin/bash" -c "cat <<EOF > /opt/bitnami/redis/etc/sentinel.conf
      port 16379
      dir /tmp
      sentinel monitor master-node master 6379 2
      sentinel down-after-milliseconds master-node 5000
      sentinel parallel-syncs master-node 1
      sentinel failover-timeout master-node 5000
      sentinel auth-pass master-node $PASSWORD
      EOF"
      "/bin/bash" -c "redis-sentinel /opt/bitnami/redis/etc/sentinel.conf"    
      EOF'
```

I guess even without the errors the environment variable would probably not be properly set as it is within a different `bash` command. But I had as well no luck combining both, the error goes away but the environment variable is not actually set:

```yaml
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c 'bash -s <<EOF
      "/bin/bash" -c "export PASSWORD=$$(</run/secrets/password) && \
      echo $PASSWORD && \
      cat <<EOF > /opt/bitnami/redis/etc/sentinel.conf
      port 16379
      dir /tmp
      sentinel monitor master-node master 6379 2
      sentinel down-after-milliseconds master-node 5000
      sentinel parallel-syncs master-node 1
      sentinel failover-timeout master-node 5000
      sentinel auth-pass master-node $PASSWORD
      EOF"
      "/bin/bash" -c "redis-sentinel /opt/bitnami/redis/etc/sentinel.conf"
      EOF'
```

Comment: Include a [mre], this is too broad

Comment: Why is this too broad? The question is quite specific: How can I export an environment variable from a file and write it into another file within a single bash script using bash heredoc? I would love to include an example, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to write complex entrypoint scripts into a `docker-compose.yml` file.  In particular, if you're embedding `sh -c` inside an `sh -c` invocation, it's a good time to refactor.

I'd put a lot of these parts into the Docker image itself.  For instance, you can create a template configuration file:

```
# sentinel.conf.tmpl
port 16379
dir /tmp
sentinel monitor master-node master 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds master-node 5000
sentinel parallel-syncs master-node 1
sentinel failover-timeout master-node 5000
sentinel auth-pass master-node $PASSWORD
```

Assuming you have [GNU envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) available (Ubuntu-based images probably will; Alpine-based images probably won't) you can create a simple wrapper script that gets the password, rewrites the config file, and then runs the main container command:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh
set -e

# Retrieve the password
export PASSWORD=$(cat /run/secrets/password)

# Rewrite the config file
envsubst \
  < /opt/bitnami/redis/etc/sentinel.conf.tmpl \
  > /opt/bitnami/redis/etc/sentinel.conf

# Run the main container command
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile you'd stitch these parts together

```sh
COPY sentinel.conf.tmpl /opt/bitnami/redis/etc/
COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["redis-sentinel", "/opt/bitnami/redis/etc/sentinel.conf"]
```

And you wouldn't override `entrypoint:` or `command:` in your `docker-compose.yml` at all.

Comment: You are probably right, although the script is working without the variable substitution and I love the simplicity of NOT having to build an extra image but being able to use the default one with a custom entrypoint supplied via docker compose. Anyway, I really appreciate your answer so thanks a lot as this is probably what I will do if I can't find an answer to my original question